# Are the reflected and absorbed components of an antenna actually orthogonal?

Tags: rf, rfid

I'm having a discrepancy between mathematics and my gut sense of reality.  (Application: trying to figure out how much reflection I'm going to see in my package.  I can tweak the CMOS, but I'm stuck with a package)  RF is not my strongest area.

An electromagnetic wave (RF), in a planar sense, has absorbed component and a reflected component.  These two components are orthogonal over the interval \$\left[0,2\pi\right]\$ and is represented by

\begin{align}
0 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}  cos(x)sin(x) dx,
\label{eqn:sincos}
\end{align}
where, the reflected component is real, represented by (cos(x)) and is the "inphase" component, I. The absorbed component is imaginary, represented by (sin(x)) and is the "quadrature" component, Q.  Mathematically, the absorption of the RF wave can be modulated by changing the imaginary component.

What this means is that mathematically, everything seems the I and Q components will be orthogonal, but I "feel" that this is not necessarily true.

The question:  Is the actual behavior as pretty as the mathematics?

Comment: I suspect that I am not the only person who doesn't have the faintest idea what you are talking about. Can you break it down into simpler steps, and explain in a little more detail the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: My car has three wheels. How much pressure should I put in the tires to turn it from red to blue ? @DaveTweed I think he's asking if an incident wave is always orthogonal (180° shifted) to it's reflected component at an interface.

Comment: @MaximGi: That's just one of the reasons I'm confused. "Orthogonal" normally means a 90° relationship, not 180°.

Comment: Your question is strange. You make an assertion about what an EM wave comprises. This does not compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the right picture of what's going on. Not least, that 0=integral equation. While it might be correct in a mathematical sense for some specific application, as Obi-Wan would say while waving his hand, 'this is not the application you are looking for'.

The reflected component can bear any phase relationship to the incident wave, depending on what is doing the reflection. A low resistive impedance and a high impedance will reflect in opposite senses, a capacitive or inductive reactance will reflect in quadrature to those, and in opposite senses to each other. When you have a reflection on the end of a significant path length, like the leg of a package, then it will rotate round all 360 degrees as move along the track.

The absorbed component is, by definition, in phase with the incident signal.

If you choose to represent any signal as I and Q components, then they are in quadrature by definition, not because of any property of the signal, or circuit that it's passing through.

Forget breaking the signal down into components, and incorrect notions about the phase relationship between absorbed and reflected waves. Concentrate instead on the point by point impedance of the transmission line that passes from your active device, through the pad, bond wire if there is one, package lead, PCB pad, and into transmission line on the board. Although you sound like only the IC designer, you are also responsible for the IC to board interface (you can't use a chip you can't mount!) which includes the recommended footprint, and possibly the board thickness and material to ensure a good transition to the final transmission line on the board.

Analyse each part of that path in terms of length and impedance of transmission line, though the bond wire could be treated as lumped inductance, and the bonding pads as lumped C to ground, and then cascade those in a suitable RF simulator, and see what you get.

Hint 1, the closer each part of it stays to the same impedance, the better.

Hint 2, you only have to worry about the relative phasing of reflected waves if your interface is electrically long, and different 'bad bits' are reflecting significant signal, and they are adding up badly as the frequency changes. Then you are really in trouble. Shorten your interface, or design the impedances better to reflect less.

Hint 3, absorbed signals are never seen again. A good interface should not have lots of loss, on inputs that creates noise, on outputs it robs you of output power. But it improves matching.

Comment: Thank you!  This summary is a great help, especially the hints.  I'll start digging from here.

Comment: So ADS, which is a simulator, was giving me perfect results.  Apparently, if it does not converge with the given values, it defaults to something safe, and in this case, mathematically perfect.  Fun fact to store away.  If the results are too good to be true, they are, but it never hurts to check.